# How can I get classname which has been created by js?

Tags: javascript, class

As you can see I'm creating that html part with js, but after I generated the 'nav_list-item' class I can't access to it later. I want to add an active class to the 'nav_list-item'

```js
const navItems = [
    {
        name: "Home",
        link: "#",
        icons: "fa-house",
        class: "active"
    },
    {
        name: "Projects",
        link: "#project",
        icons: "fa-briefcase",
        class: ""
    }
    ];

    const nav_list = document.querySelector('.nav_list');

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        let displayNav = navItems.map((item) => {
            return `
            <li class="nav_list-item ${item.class}">
                <a href="${item.link}" class="nav_link">${item.name}</a>
                <a href="${item.link}" class="nav_link-mobile">
                    <i class="fa-solid ${item.icons} nav_icon"></i>
                </a>
            </li>`;
        }).join("");
        
        nav_list.innerHTML = displayNav;
    });

    /* Add active state to nav */
    const nav_lists = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_list-item');

    nav_lists.forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav_lists.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('active'));
            e.classList.add('active');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Where is `navItems`? It's missing from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it INSIDE load event.

Works for me

```
const nav_list = document.querySelector('.nav_list');
const navItems = [
  {
    class: 'class-1',
    link: 'link-1',
    icons: 'icon-1',
    name: 'name-1'
  },
  {
    class: 'class-2',
    link: 'link-2',
    icons: 'icon-2',
    name: 'name-2'
  },
  {
    class: 'class-3',
    link: 'link-3',
    icons: 'icon-3',
    name: 'name-3'
  }
]
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let displayNav = navItems.map((item) => {
        return `
        <li class="nav_list-item ${item.class}">
            <span href="${item.link}" class="nav_link">${item.name}</span>
            <a href="${item.link}" class="nav_link-mobile">
                <i class="fa-solid ${item.icons} nav_icon"></i>
            </a>
        </li>`;
    }).join("");
    
    nav_list.innerHTML = displayNav;

    const nav_lists = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_list-item');
    nav_lists.forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            console.log(ev);
            nav_lists.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('active'));
            e.classList.add('active');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: BTW, to avoid that "Load events" you can mark you script as `defer`, and it will be executed after dom is loaded.

Read more here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer